# Want to optimize code for captured image resize and rotate using canvas of html5, which now giving low memory warning on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, optimization, memory-management, canvas

I have written code which will capture photo using camera and show it as snapshot. But before showing it as snapshot I am resizing image and rotate (if captured image is horizontal). This re-sized image is binary content which is less in size so uploading it on server becomes quick. Now I want to optimize code so that it will work better with low memory.

Problem facing:
On mobile device, sometimes chrome browser showing "unable to complete previous operation due to low memory".

Could be possible solution (i think but with question):
Processing image in chunks, will make think work better?

Thanks in advance for your help.

You may see working code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kamlesh_bhure/YpejU/)

or

Working sample code

```
<style>
#yourimage {
    width:100%;
}
.imgWeightHght {
    height: 290px !important;
    width: 220px !important;
}
.captureInsuPanel img {
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
}
.newLoaderMask {
    display: none;
    background: #E5E5E5;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 10;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0.8;
    z-index: 999;
}
</style>

    <div id="mask" class="newLoaderMask">
        <img src="http://jimpunk.net/Loading/wp-content/uploads/loading1.gif" width="200" id="loader" />
    </div>
    <input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera" id="takePictureField" />
    <div class="captureInsuPanel">
        <img id="yourimage" class="imgWeightHght" width="500" />
    </div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#takePictureField").on("change", gotPic);
});

var max_width   =   1000;
var max_height  =   1000;

function gotPic(event) {
    if (event.target.files.length == 1 && event.target.files[0].type.indexOf("image/") == 0) {
        var image = event.target.files[0];
        processCapturedImage(image, 90, max_width, max_height, $("#yourimage"));
    }
}

function processCapturedImage(image, angle, max_width, max_height, thumbNailImage) {
    $('#mask').show();

    //create a hidden canvas object we can use to create new rotated image
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.id = "hidden_canvas_old";
    canvas.style.display = "none";
    document.body.appendChild(canvas);

    //create a hidden canvas object we can use to create the new cropped &/or resized image data
    var canvas_new = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas_new.id = "hidden_canvas_new";
    canvas_new.style.display = "none";
    document.body.appendChild(canvas_new);

    var fileLoader = new FileReader(),
        imageObj = new Image();

    if (image.type.indexOf("image/") == 0) {
        fileLoader.readAsDataURL(image);
    } else {
        alert('File is not an image');
    }
    fileLoader.onload = function () {
        var data = this.result;
        imageObj.src = data;
    };

    fileLoader.onabort = function () {
        alert("The upload was aborted.");
    };

    fileLoader.onerror = function () {
        alert("An error occured while reading the file.");
    };

    // set up the images onload function which clears the hidden canvas context, 
    // draws the new image then gets the blob data from it
    imageObj.onload = function () {
        var imgWidth = this.width;
        var imgHeight = this.height;
        if (imgWidth > imgHeight) {
            //Rotate horizontal image to vertical and resizing is needed
            rotateAndResize(this, imgWidth, imgHeight, angle, max_width, max_height, thumbNailImage);
        } else {
            //no need to rotate only resizing is needed
            resize(this, imgWidth, imgHeight, max_width, max_height, thumbNailImage);
        }
    };
    imageObj.onabort = function () {
        alert("Image load was aborted.");
    };

    imageObj.onerror = function () {
        alert("An error occured while loading image.");
    };

}

function rotateAndResize(image, imgWidth, imgHeight, angle, max_width, max_height, thumbNailImage) {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("hidden_canvas_old"),
        ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    var widthHalf = imgWidth / 2,
        heightHalf = imgHeight / 2;

    canvas.width = imgWidth;
    canvas.height = imgWidth;
    //clear canvas 
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.save();
    //set coordinate to rotate canvas 
    ctx.translate(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);
    //rotate canvas with given angle
    ctx.rotate(angle * Math.PI / 180);
    //draw image on rotated canvas with given coordinate
    ctx.drawImage(image, -widthHalf, -widthHalf);

    ctx.restore();

    var tempCanvas = document.getElementById("hidden_canvas_new"),
        tCtx = tempCanvas.getContext("2d");

    tempCanvas.width = imgHeight;
    tempCanvas.height = imgWidth;
    /*
     * Crop rotated image from old canvas to remove white space 
     * So that canvas will have only image content without extra padding
     */
    tCtx.drawImage(canvas, canvas.width - imgHeight, 0, imgHeight, imgWidth, 0, 0, imgHeight, imgWidth);
    tCtx.restore();
    //Delete unwanted canvas to reduce page size
    canvas.remove();

    /**
     * Resizing Rotated image
     */
    // calculate the width and height, constraining the proportions
    if (imgWidth > imgHeight) {
        if (imgWidth > max_width) {
            imgHeight = Math.round(imgHeight *= max_width / imgWidth);
            imgWidth = max_width;
        }
    } else {
        if (imgWidth > max_height) {
            imgWidth = Math.round(imgWidth *= max_height / imgHeight);
            imgHeight = max_height;
        }
    }
    var tempCanvasTemp = tempCanvas;
    tempCanvas.remove();

    var tempCanvas1 = document.createElement("canvas"),
        tCtx1 = tempCanvas1.getContext("2d");

    tempCanvas1.id = 'hidden_canvas_new';
    tempCanvas1.style.display = 'none';
    tempCanvas1.width = imgHeight;
    tempCanvas1.height = imgWidth;

    tCtx1.drawImage(tempCanvasTemp, 0, 0, imgHeight, imgWidth);
    tCtx1.restore();

    document.body.appendChild(tempCanvas1);

    thumbNailImage.attr("src", tempCanvas1.toDataURL('image/jpeg'));
    $('#mask').hide();
}

function resize(image, imgWidth, imgHeight, max_width, max_height, thumbNailImage) {
    /**
     * Resizing image
     */
    // calculate the width and height, constraining the proportions
    if (imgWidth > imgHeight) {
        if (imgWidth > max_width) {
            //height *= max_width / width;
            imgHeight = Math.round(imgHeight *= max_width / imgWidth);
            imgWidth = max_width;
        }
    } else {
        if (imgWidth > max_height) {
            //width *= max_height / height;
            imgWidth = Math.round(imgWidth *= max_height / imgHeight);
            imgHeight = max_height;
        }
    }
    var tempCanvas = document.getElementById("hidden_canvas_new"),
        tCtx = tempCanvas.getContext("2d");

    tempCanvas.width = imgWidth;
    tempCanvas.height = imgHeight;

    tCtx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, imgWidth, imgHeight);

    thumbNailImage.attr("src", tempCanvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg'));

    $('#mask').hide();
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using MediaDevices.getUserMedia() ([documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia)) for browsers which support it, you don't need to resize the photo as you can request the size of the photo.

Several examples:

- http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/
- https://github.com/addyosmani/getUserMedia.js

Answer (score 0):

as far as I know getUserMedia() supports the maximum resolution of the video
So if you have a 12M camera, but video is maximum 720p then you can set image quality to maximum 720p